# How to use variable of one class(component) in another class(component) in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 (TypeScript). To make it simple, there are two files: `A.ts` and `B.ts`.

How to use AAA(in A.ts) in the class of B.ts? Thanks! I spent over a day, but still have not succeeded...

**A.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'foo'
})
@View({
    template:`

    `
})
export class Foo{
    AAA:DataClass = new DataClass(); // AAA is here.
}
```

**B.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'bar'
})
@View({
    template:`

    `
})
export class Bar{
    constructor(){
        // How can I use AAA here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on relations between your components:

1. If you use a component `A` **inside of a view** of a component `C` you can use [`@ViewChild`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.ts#L346) property decorator to get reference to the `A` component (you'll can use `A` component only after [`afterViewInit`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces.ts#L378) lifecycle hook will be called).
2. If you use a component `B` **as a content** of a component `B` you can use [`@ContentChild`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.ts#L243) property decorator to get reference to the `B` component (you'll can use `B` component only after [`afterContentInit`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces.ts#L283) lifecycle hook will be called).
3. If you want to get the component where your component is located, you can use [@Host()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L237) and [@Inject()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L44) parameter decorators.

Take a look at the next example (see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQ8v5xBuPdoY0Ki4cQyN?p=preview)):

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ContentChild, Host, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({ selector: 'a-cmp' /* ... */ })
class A {
  greet = 'Hello, I\'m A!!!'
}

@Component({ selector: 'b-cmp' /* ... */ })
class B {
  greet = 'Hello, I\'m B!!!'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'c-cmp',
  directives: [A],
  template: '<a-cmp></a-cmp><ng-content></ng-content><div>c-template</div>'
})
class C {
  @ViewChild(A) a: A;
  @ContentChild(B) b: B;

  constructor(@Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => App)) app: App) {
    console.log(app.greet);
  }
  afterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.a.greet);
  }
  afterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.b.greet);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [B, C],
  template: '<c-cmp><b-cmp></b-cmp></c-cmp>'
})
export class App {
  greet = 'Hello, I\'m App!!!'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, alexpods, this is a really detailed and complete help. I will try first and let you know the result!

Comment: Thanks, alexpods, feels like I have sooooo many things to learn!